# Jenkins doesn't allow my build token

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have set up a build token so that I can remotely trigger jobs on a jenkins that is setup with authentication.

However, when I try to use curl then it tries to redirect me to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

In this case Jenkins path based authorization is not allowing you to get to that URL, even though you have a token for it.

Try the build root token plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin

This gives a different URL pattern that bypasses this, so you can trigger it from curl.

Comment: Do you know the url to trigger a job which is in a folder?